# jquery accordion with different width's

Tags: jquery, css, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I want the following:

- my first header (and associated pannel) is further left then all the other pannels
- the right edge of all accordion element should be justified

**jQuery accordion**

```
+---------+
|header 1 |
+---------+
|  ...    |
|content1 |
|         |
+---------+
  +-------+
  |header2|
  +-------+
  |header3|
  +-------+
  |  ...  |
  |cont.3 |
  |       |
  +-------+
```

I don't know if it's important, but I add accordion dynamically (after page has loaded already).

**EDIT:**

Adding accordion elements and update the accordion afterwards worked. That's basically what I did:

```
        var header = document.createElement("h3");
        $(header).css({"width": "350px","margin-left": "50px"})
        header.innerHTML = "Header Text";
        $("#accordion").append(header);
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        $(div).css({"width": "350px","margin-left": "50px"});
        div.innerHTML = "Pannel Text";
        $("#accordion").append(div);
        $("#accordion").accordion("refresh");
```

Comment: I want the code you tried

Comment: I tried to access the automatically (by jQuery) generated css files. But it didn't work properly (since I have to call `$("#accordion").accordion("refresh");` method after having added another accordion element). Another solution may be wrapping some div around the accordion elements. If you think, I haven't tried anything the last few hour's, your on the wrong path...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something that seems to be like you want :

**Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/CzVhk/

**CSS [extract]** :

```
#accordion a{
    margin-left:50px;
}
#accordion div{
    margin-left:50px;
}
#accordion a:first-child{
    margin-left:0px;
}
#accordion a:first-child + div{
    margin-left:0px;
}
```

**HTML** :

```
<div id="accordion">
    <a href="#one" class="first">Recent Posts</a>
    <div id="one">
        this is some info.
    </div>

    <a href="#two">Popular Posts</a>
    <div id="two">
        this is some more info.
    </div>

    <a href="#three">Archived Posts</a>
    <div id="three">
        this is even more info.
    </div>
    <a href="#four">Archived Posts</a>
    <div id="four">
        this is even more info.
    </div>
</div>
```